# Cyclers To Mercury?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, trajectory, interplanetary, mercury, low-energy-transfer

Is it possible to establish a practical 'cycler' transportation system between Earth and Mercury?  The concept involves a small, manned payload (7.5 mt or less) doing the Earth departure and Mercury Orbit Insertion burns.  The crew inhabits the pre-deployed Cycler and, prior to Mercury encounter, converts water stored on the cycler into the propellants needed for the MOI burn.

Principle numbers for the concept are: Mercury's orbital period: 87.9 days; the Mercury-Earth synodic period: 115.9 days; the Earth's orbital period: 365.25 days and the cycler's orbital period.  Several periods are possible, but I arbitrarily chose a 351.6 day orbit.  This gives a transfer time (either way) of 175.8 days.  Evidently, the match-up is not exact enough to prevent a larger delta-V than desired.

Comment: Would you accept a double cycler Earth to Mercury with conjunction at Venus? One problem with a direct Earth Mercury cycler that I can see is the orbit of Venus (close to half inclination to that of Mercury w.r.t. Earth) so its synodic period with Earth (about 8/5 years) and Mercury (about 6/16 years) should be considered too. One starting point: [Planetary Moon Cycler Trajectories (PDF)](http://trs-new.jpl.nasa.gov/dspace/bitstream/2014/40318/1/07-0390.pdf)

Comment: Yes, subject to the magnitude of velocity change required at Mercury.  If the cycler can put the manned vehicle in a position relative to Mercury that allows an MOI from the cycler's orbit with propellant mass at or below a 'conventional' Hohmann transfer.  Thanks for the excellent link!  I will definitely be reviewing it. ., .

Comment: Well for the cycler part ("Castle") that stays in the "free-return" trajectory, the ΔV requirements should be minimal (i.e. corrections) once the cycler orbit is established. But the "Taxi" that departs it and is later catching the cycler during one of its next legs the ΔV required would be similar to direct Hohmann transfer. So this then becomes an exercise in mass economy, how much of it can stay in cycler orbit and how much of it is required for the circularisation at Mercury. Delta-v will always stay the same, but the mass that needs to achieve it _might_ be substantially smaller.

Comment: Yes, delta-V stays the same.  The difference is in the mass being accelerated.

Comment: At Earth, the payload being accelerated is just the crew module and the dry mass of the propulsion stage.  At Mercury, the mass is exactly the same.  The trick here (well, one of them. . .) is to have the MOI delta-V be at or less than the delta-V for the Earth departure - the propellants for this maneuver having been loaded from the cycler's supplies.  My concern is if thye cycler's orbit meets Mercury's orbit and Mercury is not EXACTLY at the point where the cycler meets the orbit, , ,  Will the delta-V needed to make up the difference exceed the cycler's supply of propellant?

Comment: The delta-V for the MOI is as high as 9.5 for 'least acceptable' flight opportunities.

Comment: There's IMO nothing to be gained by consuming the Castle's mass for propulsion, since you'd then be spending its kinetic energy that was already invested in it. The whole point of cycler orbits with the Castle and Taxi parts is that the Castle's mass in a cycler orbit is essentially for free once you've set it into free-return cycler trajectory and all you need to worry about is the required acceleration for the Taxi part. See e.g. [What uses would the Aldrin-Cycler have?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/3880/49) Delta-V is largely irrelevant here, it's about the reuse-to-expend mass ratio.

Comment: Ok.  I think I'm beginning to see where my confusion was.  ". . .consuming the Castle's mass. . ." sort of throws me a bit.  The cycler carries propellant.  This is used for the MOI maneuver.  It can just as easily be used for mid-course maneuvers to ensure the manned  'taxi' gets the best delta-V for MOI.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14273/discussion-between-mercuryplus-and-tildalwave)

Comment: Migrate to [bicycles.SE]! :-D

Comment: Expecting Hohmann like delta Vs for the taxis is optimistic. It assumes the Castle would be on an Hohmann like orbit. For Aldrin cyclers, for example, the Castle is on a decidedly unHohmann like orbit. the Aldrin Cycler crosses Mars orbit at a healthy angle and Taxi rendezvous is much more delta V than TMI to a Hohmann.

Comment: A roughly Hohmann Mercury cycler may be doable though. 22 synodic periods is about is about 8 days short of seven years. 12 Earth Murcury Hohmann orbits is about 25 days short of 7 years. So a fly by of both the planets each 7 years is doable with roughly Hohmann cyclers. Some rotation of the orbit's line of apsides.

Comment: But that rotation of the line of apsides spells trouble. Mercury has a healthy inclination of 7 degrees. You want fly bys near the ascending and descending nodes or you have big plane change expense.

Comment: The even the V infinities for a coplanar Merucy Hohmann are quite high: 7.5 km/s departing from earth and 9.6 km/s arriving at Mercury. Since Mercury's shall gravity has much less Oberth benefit, no atmosphere for aerobraking, the Taxi delta V at Mercury's end is steep. It'd take around 11 km/s for a taxi to land on Mercury. Propellent mass would be around 10 times that of the taxi's dry mass.

Answer (score 3):

Usable Mercury cyclers exist.

Given the large inclination of Mercury, we want the encounter to happen along the line of apsides, thereby requiring a quasi-periodic stationary cycler. The simplest type of cycler in this family is a high periapse fly by ellipse, ideally close to a Hohmann transfer orbit. This requires that the planets' synodic period is a simple fraction of the orbital period of either of the planets. Furthermore, the orbital period of the cycler must be close to the previously stated quasi-period, divided by an integer.

Interesting quasi-periods include:

3, -17.36375
19,  10.02959
22,  -7.33416
41,   2.69542

(Synodic periods, inaccuracy in degrees)

As for actual appearance of the planetary alignments, a usable launch window would in worst case appear within a decade in the Mercury-Earth system.

The 22 and the 41 synodic period cycler are the two most interesting. The 22 (7 year) orbit offers a trajectory suitable for reuse 4-5 times, at a relatively low delta-v cost. This is because the orbital period of 0.5385 years, compared to the 0.5327 years for a perfect Hohmann transfer to the ascending node, has a close to minimal vinf.

That is also the case for the even better 41 (13 year) orbit, where the same comparison is 0.61905 years to 0.61853 years for a descending node transfer. (The deviation from a Hohmann transfer is negligible.) A slight boost to a 0.63636 empty 7 year cycle every 46 years reduces the angular drift to 1.635 degrees per century, allowing stability for maybe as long as a millennium.

This type of cycler does not offer two-way transportation, so two cyclers are necessary. (One inbound, one outbound.)