# Are there any proposals for a permanent orbital interplanetary ferry?

Tags: mars, interplanetary, travel, earth

I believe I read in a book once a description of a kind of interplanetary ferry that would orbit the sun and regularly pass different planets like Mars and Earth. The idea of the ferry is to have a place to stay for astronauts on their long journey apart from being strapped into the confines of a single space ship. I find it hard, however, to find anything on the web on this idea. Would it be possible for such a ferry to frequent more than two planets with a single orbit?

Comment: What you're thinking of is an Aldrin cycler http://buzzaldrin.com/space-vision/rocket_science/aldrin-mars-cycler/

Comment: I'd think that's unlikely because the concept has to do with the harmony of two orbital periods. Putting a third object in there should make it very rare. But me and orbmech aren't best friends, so I'm looking forward to a real answer. I love the concept, for one planet. It is a kind of non scifi medium sized project which could happen and make sense this century.

Comment: @LocalFluff The concept of the interplanetary cycler is indeed based on the harmony of orbital periods, and indeed does sound like what the OP is asking. As Aldrin showed, they're not as rare as one might think.

Comment: Related question: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3880/what-uses-would-the-aldrin-cycler-have

Comment: the delta-v to go from earth c3=0 to mars c3=0 is relatively low (~1.5km/s), so one could consider a ferry that stays in space and performs orbit transfers using fuel brought by the taxis.

Comment: Kim Stanley Robinson loves cyclers in his fiction books (in particular Blue Mars and 3142). Although I don't think he goes into detail about their schedules, you get the impression they are fairly 'chaotic' rather than regular, they travel between 3 or more bodies (i.e. venus, earth, mars) and select the next one based on the available alignments. However in KSR's world cyclers co-exist with fusion drives which can do Earth-Mars in 2 weeks and can easily rendezvous with cyclers. This makes cyclers more like cruise-liners than energy-saving transportation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Mars cyclers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_cycler) have already been mentioned in the comments, with the Aldrin cycler being one example of them. The *castle* parts of them could be seen as *ferries*, and the visiting *taxis* as means of embarking and disembarking during visits of planets along their routes.

And three or more bodies cyclers are also possible, for example the so-called [resonant cyclers](http://starsdestination.blogspot.com/2012/05/resonant-cyclers.html) of which Laplace resonant cyclers in the Jupiter system might be the best example and are made possible due to the Laplace orbital resonance between Io, Europa and Ganymede (see e.g. [Laplace-resonant triple-cyclers for missions to Jupiter](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0094576511000683), A. E. Lynam et al.). These can be either *gravity assist* or *visit* cyclers.

There could also be *visit* only non-resonant cyclers with highly elliptical heliocentric orbits that stretch orbital altitude of several planet but never intersect their orbits (slight inclanation of the cycler w.r.t. orbital plane of involved planets), but those would be less useful in terms of delta-v savings for the *taxis* to and fro planets, tho they could still provide significant mass savings with their reusable *castle* parts, depending on utility they could provide (see e.g. [this thread](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3880/49) for some suggested uses).

Of course, there might be an infinite number of cyclers and other periodic or quasi-periodic orbits between multiple celestial bodies. Problem with finding those is the computational intensity mostly limiting analysis to non-exhaustive R3BP (restrictive three-body problem) and taking *shortcuts* such as restricting search to best possible candidates, natural equilibrium between celestial bodies, and using precomputed invariant manifolds in (simplified) R3BP space, then *stitching* these together to design more complex trajectories involving multiple targets. Adding more bodies to such analysis greatly intensifies search for additional possible resonant cyclers (or other low energy trajectories, often the lot of them known under a moniker of *[Interplanetary Transport Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interplanetary_Transport_Network)*) within our Solar system, and is still one of the areas where human intuition, for lack of a better word, often trumps all the supercomputers that we task with solving such problems.

Throw at this problem also the possibility of using propulsion methods that don't consume any reaction mass, such as momentum exchange tethers, solar or magnetic sails, beam powered propulsion, ramjets and similar, or settle for shorter term use or that your *ferry* system doesn't have to be self-sufficient (dependent on supply of consumables and would require maintenance), and the number of possibilities becomes infinite.

Comment: In other words, no.

Comment: @GdD You mean if there are proposals? Depends on what that means, I guess. Many such cyclers have been proposed and discussed (e.g. Buzz Aldrin has been fairly vocal, but there are others). But I can't think of any that would currently be _seriously_ considered tho. Where _seriously_ is _someone threw a lot of money into it_.

Comment: Well, there's nothing to ferry for one thing.

Comment: @GdD Agreed, this is something that will be looked into more with establishment of industry. Tho those Jovian resonant cyclers could also be used for scientific missions. Actually, come think of it, I did read some proposal utilizing that. I'll see if I can find it... Edit: Found these _[Data Clippers](http://www.centauri-dreams.org/?p=14396)_ but that's not exactly what I had in mind, IIRC it had something to do with the EJSM/Laplace (not the paper I mention in the answer). The search continues...