# Why does the Buzz Aldrin Mars Cycler not play a larger role in planning for Mars exploration?

Tags: mars, crewed-spaceflight, radiation, low-energy-transfer

In 1985 Buzz Aldrin AKA “Dr. Rendezvous” proposed using a pair of space station habitats in solar cycler orbits as  “Up and Down Escalators” for crewed Earth-Mars transfers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_cycler

The primary advantage is to reduce transit time and propellant consumption by leaving the most massive components in solar orbit. These two advantages are connected since required radiation shielding mass is proportional to transit time. None of the active shielding methods proposed to date appear to offer a weight savings over bulk material shielding. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.733.9425&rep=rep1&type=pdf .

[image]

Cycler space stations (“Castles”)  uses were outlined in [What uses would the Aldrin-Cycler have?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3880/what-uses-would-the-aldrin-cycler-have)

In particular, radiation shielding mass, habitat and solar panels can be left in orbit instead of being repeatedly relaunched.

The big downside appears to be the delta V at each end of the transfer, but this is only being applied to the small mass of cargo and its "taxi", not the entire “castle”. Propellant consumption is proportional to the mass being "delta-ed".

The cycler concept seems to attract little attention compared with discrete spacecraft using Hohmann transfer orbits.

Question: Why does the Buzz Aldrin Mars Cycler not play a larger role in planning for Mars exploration?

Comment: I wonder if there is any financial downside to building two large space stations in deep space that must be maintained for decades.

Comment: The answer would depend on the total cost and the best alternative. If the best alternative is building all those space station facilities into every interplanetary ship and launching it twice each round trip, the numbers might look good. The Devil, as always, is in the details.

Comment: Sure, if the Funding Entity is willing to go all in. Big Plans that involve a lot of up front spending are tough sells. Look up the Integrated Program Plan sometime.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Transportation_System

Comment: You make a practical point. The Cycler is more along the lines of Elon's, "Building ~1,000 Starships to create a self-sustaining city on Mars' is SpaceX's Mission" type hand-waving.

Comment: Why do cyclers not play a larger role in planning for Mars exploration? For about the same reason that Aircraft Carriers did not feature very largely in the Wright Brothers' plans for their Flier.

Comment: Wright Brothers flew their first controlled flight in 1903. The first purpose-designed aircraft carrier to be laid down was HMS Hermes in 1918.

Comment: @woody ***EXACTLY***. The first controlled flight to Mars was in 1962, the launch of the first Aldrin Cycler is not expected until <<error, date not found>>, so it is somewhat hard to incorporate in into current plans, and putting all current Mars plans on hold until we figure out the cycler concept is a bit... slow. AT the time of the wright brothers the concept of a mobile air base was very well known (for airships though), but not actualized, which is *exactly* where the ALdrin Cycler is, for us, right now.

Comment: @CuteKItty_pleaseStopBArking  I’m not suggesting “putting all current Mars plans on hold”.  I’m suggesting the role of cyclers be included in the planning. If large scale Mars exploration +/- colonization occurs, many shipments of crew and cargo will be needed. They have different requirements for transit. Cargo is in no hurry, needs no elbow room, no consumables or shielding. Opposite for crew. Having cycler transit for crew and Hohmann transfers for bulk cargo has potential advantages, but does not need to be in place for exploration to start.

Answer (score 9):

A cycler makes sense where there is expected to be a small but steady shuffle of humans back and forth between Earth and Mars on a fixed timeline. Notably boarding and leaving a cycler involves more DV than a Hoheman transfer would take so only makes sense where 'buy once' costs boosting life support and radiation shielding add up through re-use.

It becomes less useful if:

- life support technology is not closed and needs regular topping up (see DV penalty)
- The bulk of the mission mass is actually needed at Mars (landers, habs etc)
- Abort options are desirable ([parking vehicle at Mars may be helpful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Martian_(film)))
- Some/all of the crew intend to stay on Mars
- Your business model is making rockets designed to refuel on Mars
  (SpaceX)
- Aim is to minimise cost of a bootprint on Mars

There have been a number of different Mars [proposals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_mission_to_Mars) over the years and most of them have probably looked at cyclers, but have run it against the needs list and found it was not a value add, most likely on the cost two re-usable cyclers over one (probably simpler) single purpose transit vehicle. Note that humans, especially humans with elections to win are not necessarily [good long term planners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed_gratification).